# A single word to describe a belligerent attitude shift when confronted

Tags: word-usage

I have experienced this human condition in the past. It was a situation where someone asked me a simple question about what I was doing. I rather lost my composure and became somewhat aggressive and belligerent. All the time I knew that the person behind me would support me. I see this a lot with mall cops, police, etc, and it always seems to be limited to persons with some kind of assumed or real authority. This has puzzled me for a long time. There must be a word for it.

Comment: the term "bristled" comes to mind.  Sort of an angry defensive reaction ... almost certainly from the reaction of a porcupine has when threatened.  'fiestily defensive' would not quite be 'belligerent' though.

Comment: Can you add a sentence showing how this word would be used?  (Put an X or ___ where the word would go.)

Comment: Roger,   I will try to condense my thoughts into something that conveys my question. This is a condition of the mind and it's state under specific circumstances. There has to be a back-up authority in order for this condition to exist. The person or animal has to be engaged with a third party. The third party has to be either asking for something or intruding. A sentence that would need this word would be: When I approached the officer and asked for directions to the nearest public facility, he ______, drew his pistol, and ordered me to the ground. ("went ape-s##t" is my best answer)

Answer (score 2):

To a certain extent, I think it depends on *how* belligerent.

Lightly: **Defensive**

*Mary always turned the argument around. No matter how obvious her own problems were, and no matter how well-meaning her friends were in trying to help, she became defensive and accused her friends of the exact same problems!*

Moderate: **Confrontational**

*Instead of taking advice from his boss, Steve became confrontational when presented with problems in his evaluations.*

Severe: **Explosive**

Even just a minor slight pur Grey into an explosive rage. Just looking at his face, you could tell his nose had been broken several times.

Comment: The more I think about it, I see that this condition is not limited to humans as I noted in the first post. Our family once had a terrier dog that would bristle and begin barking at any stranger.  When a family member would come out of the house and start yelling at the dog to back off, the dog would charge the stranger instead. I'm hoping for a word that identifies the transition period from a dog's cautious alarm to all out charge. Unfortunately, I don't have any psychology books at hand.